# Publishing and Hosting Oracle Apex app into WWW

Tags: oracle, web, oracle-apex, host

This question may sound silly for some of you, but I would be grateful if you could advise if it is possible to publish apex app into www?

Let's say I am going to run my testing environment under apex.oracle.... url, however I would like my production environment to be running under for example www.MyWebSite.com

Many thanks in advance for any tips.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to host your own production environment, you have two stages: setting up your server, and deploying your application.

For server setup, you've got two main options:

1. Sign up with [a specialized APEX hosting company](https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=411:4:::NO:::) who will do all the server setup and administration for you.
2. Do it yourself. You'll need to register your domain name and sign up with a hosting company. Then you'll install and configure Oracle Database, as well as a **web application server** (like Weblogic or Tomcat). Then install and configure [Oracle Rest Data Services](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/rest.html) (ORDS), which will act as the listener for APEX.

Now, once your server is ready, look at the documentation on [Deploying Your Application](https://docs.oracle.com/database/apex-5.1/HTMDB/deploying-an-application.htm#HTMDB11000). The basic steps are that you want to **export** your application from your test workspace, and **import** it into your production environment.